# Something wrong in "What will this course help you to?"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I have been told by an English teacher that after the sentence

> "This course will help me to be more relaxed and patient"

the following sentence is inadequate

> "What will this course help you to?"

Can someone please explain why?

Answer (score 3):

There are two all-purpose verbs: DO and BE; three if we include BECOME.

So:

What will this course help you to do?

What will this course help you to be?

> This course will help me to climb mountains.
>   -- Say again? What will it help you to do?

Or

> This course will help me to become a mountain climber.
>   --Sorry, I didn't hear all of what you said. What will this course help you to be?